# How can I avoid log(0) in the implementation of the categorical cross-entropy loss function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, loss-function, cross-entropy

I have implemented the cross-entropy and its gradient in Python, but I'm not sure if it's correct. My implementation is for a neural network.

```
yEst = np.array([1, 6, 3, 5]).T # output of a softmax function in last layer

y = np.array([0, 6, 3, 0]).T

def crossEntropy(y, yEst):
    return  - np.sum(y*np.log(yEst),axis =0)

def crossEntropyDerivative(y, yEst):
    m = y.shape[0]
    c = np.sum(yEst - y, axis = 0)
    return c/m
```

How can I avoid log(0)? Furthermore, is the gradient implemented correctly?

Comment: Just curious, there are well defined loss functions in tensorflow, pytorch, why not use them ?